# Can we use Microsoft Excel keywords in ubuntu's office as we are now using in Windows XP?

Tags: libreoffice

Please inform me about this as soon as possible.11.04
1. Also tell me that after installing ubuntu,is there any need to install all the MS-Office  again? Or we could be just able to carry on with our old & default MS-office?
  Please tell us about this because,we are eager to know about this and we want to install ubuntu on our PC.

Answer (score 0):

Install libreoffice on your Windows machines first and try it out. If it works to your satisfaction there, you can move on to Ubuntu without worries.

MS Office on Ubuntu is possible, but tricky and youmay run in to real difficulties down the line. I wouldn't recommend it.